# format matrix with integers and double precision in C++

Tags: c++

How could you print integers and double precision values in a matrix. 
ex.(100 34 56 77.80
    75  45 98 22.00
I am able to print the matrix except that the double values with trailing zeroes do not display the trailing zero.
I believe the answer lies within the  library but I have tried multiple combinations with no luck.
Need help.

Comment: You mean you want 22.00 to print the zeros, but don't want 100 to be printed as 100.00?

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix". There are no matrices built into C++. You are going to have to be more specific and probably show code.

Answer (score 3):

`<iomanip>` is indeed the way to go:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != nrows; ++i)
{
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j != ncols; ++j)
    {
        if (j != 0) std::cout << " ";
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill(' ') << std::setprecision(2)
                  << static_cast<double>(data[i][j]);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```